# python search from tag

Tags: python, parsing

i need help with python programming:
i need a command which can search all the words between tags from a text file.
for example in the text file has `<concept> food </concept>`. i need to search all the words between `<concept>` and `</concept>` and display them.
can anybody help please.......

Answer (score 3):

1. Load the text file into a string.
2. Search the string for the first occurrence of `<concept>` using `pos1 = s.find('<concept>')`
3. Search for `</concept>` using `pos2 = s.find('</concept>', pos1)`

The words you seek are then `s[pos1+len('<concept>'):pos2]`

Comment: This method does not take comments and tags with whitespace into account if question's author imply XML

Answer (score 3):

There is a great library for HTML/XML traversing named [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/). With it:

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulStoneSoup
soup = BeautifulStoneSoup(open('myfile.xml', 'rt').read())
for t in soup.findAll('concept'):
   print t.string
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at regular expressions. http://docs.python.org/library/re.html

If you want to have for example the tag `<i>`, try

```
text = "text to search. <i>this</i> is the word and also <i>that</i> end"
import re
re.findall("<i>(.*?)</i>",text)
```

Here's a short explanation how findall works: It looks in the given string for a given regular expression. The regular expression is `<i>(.*?)</i>`:

- `<i>` denotes just the opening tag `<i>`
- `(.*?)` creates a group and matches as much as possible until it comes to the first
- `</i>`, which concludes the tag

Note that the above solution does not mach something like

```
<i> here's a line
break </i>
```

Since you just wanted to extract *words*.

However, it is of course possible to do so:

```
re.findall("<i>(.*?)</i>",text,re.DOTALL)
```